# Vue component with three buttons with different number

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have one component thats create 3 items (boxes) with 3 buttons(I used v-for) inside each item, each button has a number inside and I want to change the number inside the button when I click on it, but now all the numbers change at the same click

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="box" v-for="message in messages" v-bind:key="message">
      <p>{{ message }}</p>
      <button class="btn" v-on:click="counter++">{{ counter }}</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "childComponent",
  data: function () {
    return {
      messages: ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3"],
      counter: 0,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

```js
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Soy el componente padre</h2>
    <child-component />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import childComponent from "./Hijo.vue";

export default {
  name: "fhaterComponent",
  components: {
    childComponent,
  },
};
</script>
```

I have the father who gets the child. I have spent all day long trying to figure out how to do it, but I am stuck

Comment: Just add your three child components into the template of the parent component? Not sure what your problem is.

Comment: I have one component thats create 3 items (boxes) with 3 buttons(I used v-for) inside each item, each button has a number inside and I want to change the number inside the button when I click on it, but now all the numbers change at the same click

Comment: You are using one ChildComponent with one state. Move your v-for to the parent and create multiple ChildComponents with their own individual state.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the buttons share the same property in data. The component will need a data structure that tracks a counter independently for each item in messages...

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="box" v-for="(counter, i) in counters" v-bind:key="i">
      <p>{{ counter.message }}</p>
      <button class="btn" v-on:click="counter.count++">{{ counter.count }}</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "childComponent",
  data: function () {
    return {
      messages: ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3"],
      counters: [],
    };
  },
  mounted () {
    this.counters = messages.map(message => ({ message, count: 0}));
    // so counters will be [ { message: "item 1" , count: 0 }, ... ]
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: It's probably better in this case to use 3 individual ChildComponents with their own state.

Answer (score 0):

You're mutating the same counter on every button.

If you create an object for each element, with it's own counter, the values will be incremented independently.

See the example bellow:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="box" v-for="value in values" v-bind:key="value.message">
      <p>{{ value.message }}</p>
      <button class="btn" v-on:click="value.counter++">
        {{ value.counter }}
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "childComponent",
  data: function () {
    return {
      values: [
        { message: "item 1", counter: 0 },
        { message: "item 2", counter: 0 },
        { message: "item 3", counter: 0 },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: You can test it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-gagarin-wifte?file=/src/App.vue